# Update old records with new information in pyspark without overwriting

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I want to update the old records based on the information I may or may not get from the new instance of the same record in pyspark.
This is what the old table/dataframe looks like

```
| FirstName | LastName | JoinDate  | SnapshotBeginDate | SnapshotEndDate |           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| John      | Doe      |2017-04-05 | 2017-05-04        | 2099-12-31      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Jane      | Smith    |2018-04-05 | 2017-05-04        | 2099-12-31 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I do not want to merely append the new data to the existing dataframe. Nor do I want to overwrite the existing record. I would instead want to update the snapshotEndDate of the old record.

For eg:

```
| FirstName | LastName | JoinDate  | SnapshotBeginDate | SnapshotEndDate |           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| John      | Doe      |2017-04-05 | 2017-05-04        | 2019-04-03      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Jane      | Smith    |2018-04-05 | 2017-05-04        | 2019-04-03|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| John      | Doe      |2017-04-05 | 2019-04-03        | 2099-12-31|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Jane      | Smith    |2018-04-05 | 2019-04-03        | 2099-12-31|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What problem do you face? Currently it sounds like that you have to create two dataframes from your data. Do your transformations on one of the dataframes and do a union with the other dataframe.

Comment: I want to update the snapshotEndDate for the old records.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do, is to create two dataframes from your data (`dfold` and `dfnew` in the following example)

```py
import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
l = [
 ('John',      'Doe'    ,  '2017-04-05',  '2017-05-04' ,        '2099-12-31'),
 ('Jane' ,      'Smith'  ,  '2018-04-05',  '2017-05-04' ,        '2099-12-31')
    ]

columns = [     'FirstName' , 'LastName', 'JoinDate'  , 'SnapshotBeginDate' , 'SnapshotEndDate']

dfold=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)
dfold = dfold.withColumn('SnapshotBeginDate',   F.to_date(dfold.SnapshotBeginDate,  'yyyy-MM-dd'))
dfold = dfold.withColumn('SnapshotEndDate',   F.to_date(dfold.SnapshotEndDate,  'yyyy-MM-dd'))
dfnew = dfold
```

You can update the SnapshotEndDate column of `dfold` and the SnapshotBeginDate of the `dfnew` with the [withColumn](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn) function. This function allows you to apply an operation to a column. You also need the current date to update the values. The python module datetime provides such a functionality (in case you don't need the current date, just specify any other date as string), but doesn't return a column. To turn the return object into a column, we can use the pyspark [lit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit) function.

```py
dfold= dfold.withColumn('SnapshotEndDate', F.lit(datetime.date.today()))
dfnew= dfnew.withColumn('SnapshotBeginDate', F.lit(datetime.date.today()))
dfold.union(dfnew).show()
```

Output:

```py
+---------+--------+----------+-----------------+---------------+ 
|FirstName|LastName|  JoinDate|SnapshotBeginDate|SnapshotEndDate| 
+---------+--------+----------+-----------------+---------------+ 
|     John|     Doe|2017-04-05|       2017-05-04|     2019-06-01| 
|     Jane|   Smith|2018-04-05|       2017-05-04|     2019-06-01| 
|     John|     Doe|2017-04-05|       2019-06-01|     2099-12-31| 
|     Jane|   Smith|2018-04-05|       2019-06-01|     2099-12-31| 
+---------+--------+----------+-----------------+---------------+
```